# Python Pony ORM Insert multiple values at once

Tags: python, database, postgresql, ponyorm

I'm trying to insert multiple values into my postgres database using Pony ORM. My current approach is very inefficient:

```
from pony.orm import *

db = Database()

class Names(db.Entity):
    first_name = Optional(str)
    last_name = Optional(str)


family = [["Peter", "Mueller"], ["Paul", "Meyer"], ...] 


@db_session
def populate_names(name_list)
    for name in name_list:
        db.insert("Names", first_name=name[0], last_name=name[1])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    db.bind(provider='postgres', user='', password='', host='', database='')
    db.generate_mappings(create_tables=True)
    populate_names(family)
```

This is just a short example but the structure of the input is the same:
a list of lists.
I'm extracting the data from several xml files and insert one "file" at a time.

Does anyone has an idea on how to put several rows of data into one insert query in Pony ORM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pony doesn't provide something special for this, you can use [`execute_values`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.execute_values) from `psycopg2.extras`. Get `connection` object from `db` to use it.

```
from psycopg2.extras import execute_values
...
names = [
    ('はると', '一温'),
    ('りく', '俐空'),
    ('はる', '和晴'),
    ('ひなた', '向日'),
    ('ゆうと', '佑篤')
]

@db_session
def populate_persons(names):
    sql = 'insert into Person(first_name, last_name) values %s'
    con = db.get_connection()
    cur = con.cursor()
    execute_values(cur, sql, names)

populate_persons(names)
```

`execute_values` is in [Fast execution helpers](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers) list so I think that iе should be the most efficient way.

Answer (score 2):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/ponyorm/pony/issues/400) in the issue tracker of PonyORM which asks for exactly this feature.

I recommend to vote for it.

Answer (score 1):

Currently I'm experimenting with PonyORM for a future project and also came to the conclusion you provided.

The only way on how to insert data in a bulky way is:

```py
# assuming data has this structure:
# [['foo','bar','bazooka'],...]
@db_session
def insert_bulk_array(field1, field2, field3):
    MyClass(field1=field1, field2=field2, field3=field3)

# assuming the data is:
# {'field1':'foo','field2':'bar','field3':'bazooka'}
@db_session
def insert_bulk_dict(data)
    MyClass(**data)
```

But from my point of view this is still somehow handy, specially when your data comes as JSON.